# Not finding variable

Tags: java, arrays

I am having problems with my program compiling to find a variable.  I have two classes for this program currently and my variable lotteryNumbers is in the first class.  It is an int array variable though so I am not sure how to insert it in this line of code.  This program is a lottery program to let people pick their tickets.  Here is the lines of code where I get my first problem of not finding the variable

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class CashBallTest
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int kicker;
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tCashLottoBall");
    System.out.println("Player picks four numbers from 1 to 33 called LottoCash Balls.  LottoCash Ball numbers must be unique from all other LottoCash Balls.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The player must also pick a CashBall from 1 to 31.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Kicker is a brand new feature you can purchase with your CashBall ticket which lets you get in on an extra drawing.");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
for(int index=0; index<lotteryNumbers.length; index++)
{
```

It is from the for(int.....   line at the bottom.

Edit*
Here is the first class which is called CashBall and has the variable in it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CashBall
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[4];
    int[] kicker = new int[4];
    int[] kickerPowerBall = new int[1];
    int yourNumbers;
    int CashBallPick;
    public CashBall(int yourNumbers, int CashBallPick)
    {
        this.yourNumbers=yourNumbers;
        this.CashBallPick=CashBallPick;
    }
    public int getYourNumbers()
    {
        return yourNumbers;
    }
    public int getCashBallPick()
    {
        return CashBallPick;
    }
    public void setYourNumbers(int yourNumbers)
    {
        this.yourNumbers=yourNumbers;
    }
    public void setCashBallPick(int CashBallPick)
    {
        this.CashBallPick=CashBallPick;
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont see where the lotteryNumbers variable is defined.

Answer (score 0):

have you defined lotteryNumbers as a protected or public variable in the class in which it is defined

Also you need to include the class int which the variable lotteryNumbers is defined if they are not in the same package

Or you can define a function get_lottery_Numbers() in the class in which it is defined and then call that method in other class.

There is an example here that can help

http://www.roseindia.net/java/javascript-array/call-method-another-class.shtml

Comment: thumbs down. Java is not Javascript. Referencing a site like that will only lead to unfortunate confusion later. (and yes, I understand that the code in the site is actually Java and they just have it misnamed. But that displays the incompetence of the web designers. Don't reference incompetence to newbies.)

Comment: @Visionary Software Solutions and @Sean Patrick Floyd Sorry Guys, I wont recommend stuff from there in future.

Answer (score 0):

You have no variable called `lotteryNumbers`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `other class` you need to declare a getter for the `lotteryNumbers` field and then use the getter method to get that field in `CashBallTest`.

Here is an example. Let's assume your other class is named `SomeClazz`. It should look like below:-

```
public final class SomeClazz {
    private final int[] lotteryNumbers;
    public SomeClazz(int[] lotteryNumbers){
        this.lotteryNumbers=lotteryNumbers;
    }
    public int[] getLotteryNumbers() {
        return lotteryNumbers;
    }

}
```

Then in your `CashBallTest` class, you should have something like below to access `lotteryNumbers`:-

```
        int[] lotteryNumbers = {1,2,3};
        SomeClazz clazz = new SomeClazz(lotteryNumbers);
        for(int index=0; index<clazz.getLotteryNumbers().length; index++){
        }
```

Now you have a way to access `lotteryNumbers` from your other class and hence no longer the unknown symbol error should appear.

Comment: This is "fixes the problem", but I get the feeling that the op is inexperienced. This simple question presents a good opportunity to show advanced principles like the Law of Demeter in action and show how to create loosely coupled designs between object that interact.

Comment: @Visionary Software Solutions - Good idea but you have to be careful on not doing information overload :-).

Answer (score 0):

If by "lotteryNumbers is in the first class" you mean that there is a field `lotteryNumbers` in the class `CashBallTest`, then the way to access it depends on how it's declared. If it is a static variable, you can refer to it by `CashBallTest.lotteryNumbers`. If it is not static, then you need to create an instance of `CashBallTest` (let's call it `test`), and then refer to it by `test.lotteryNumbers`.

Answer (score 0):

So in your CashBall class, you need:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class CashBall
{
  // you should probably initialize this variable in your constructor
  private int[] lotteryNumbers;
  public int[] getLotteryNumbers() { return lotteryNumbers; }
}
```

This defines a private variable internal to the class called lotteryNumbers and then creates a public method that exposes it to the testing class. Then you need to create a CashBall object in your CashBallTest, and access its lottery numbers. Like:

```
public class CashBallTest
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
      CashBall test = new CashBall();
      for(int index=0; index < test.getLotteryNumbers().length; index++) ;
  }
 }
```

We do this to **encapsulate** the variable such that later we can change the internal variable CashBall uses to store the lotteryNumbers without forcing other classes that use CashBall to change all their code.

For example, I could change:

```
private int[] lotteryNumbers;
```

to

```
import java.util.collections.ArrayList
private ArrayList<Integer> lotteryNumbers;
public int[] getLotteryNumbers() { 
  int[] returned; 
  return lotteryNumbers.toArray(returned);
}
```

Encapsulation is good coding practice, so be sure you get in the habit of encapsulating your privates.

For extra credit, you probably don't want to iterate across the length of the array in your test. This is bad because your test becomes dependent on CashBall having an int[]. If CashBall changes, your test has to change.

To "do it right", you should add methods inside of CashBall that handle "picking lottery numbers" (which I assume is what this first loop is trying to do), "validating lottery numbers", and "playing with kicker. Then your testing class would become like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
public class CashBallTest
{
   CashBall toTest;
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
       toTest = new CashBall(); // add parameters here as necessary
       toTest.collectUserLotteryNumbers(); // put the Scanner stuff in here. Make the menu its own void method that's called from here
       if(toTest.validateUserNumbers() == false) {
          throw new InputMismatchException("Numbers must be between 1-31, and cannot be repeated");
       }
   }
 }
```

As you gain more experience coding, you'll find yourself writing them like this:

```
public class CashBallTest
{
   CashBall toTest;
   public static void testUserCollection()
   {
      toTest = new CashBall(); // add parameters here as necessary
       toTest.collectUserLotteryNumbers(); // put the Scanner stuff in here. Make the menu its own void method that's called from here
       if(toTest.validateUserNumbers() == false) {
          throw new InputMismatchException("Numbers must be between 1-31, and cannot be repeated");
   }
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
      testUserCollection();   
   }
   }
 }
```

This allows you to break up each thing you're testing into its own particular method, making it easy to add individual tests or modify them without breaking other stuff in your main method. Once you get in this practice, you'll be ready to learn about *Unit Testing* frameworks like JUnit.